# Extracting URLs from JSON file with python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, parsing

The JSON file is like this:

```
[
        {
            "src": "https://",
            "viewcount": "0"
        },
        {
            "src": "https://",
            "viewcount": "0"
        }

]
```

I wish to extract all the values under `src` (all of which are urls) with python.

How can I do so?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try loading JSON first.

Sample output:

[image]

```
import json

myjsonstr =  '[{"src": "https://google.com","viewcount": "0"},{"src": "https://yahoo.com","viewcount": "0"}]'

myjsonobj = json.loads(myjsonstr)

for eachitem in myjsonobj:
    print(eachitem["src"])
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the `json` module. `loads` will try to parse a string (watch out, there's an extra/missing bracket in what you posted).

After that, it's a regular dict.

```py
import json

source = """[
        {
            "src": "https://",
            "viewcount": "0"
        },
        {
            "src": "https://",
            "viewcount": "0"
        }
    ]  
"""

urls = [x['src'] for x in json.loads(j)]
```

```
['https://', 'https://']
```